# Getting all of the <option> values in a <select> tag on a servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I'm trying to get all of the option values in a select to the Servlet in Java, but I can't find a way of getting the ones that are unselected. My HTML code is:

```
    <select id="cart" size="10" name="cart" onDblClick="removeFromList()">
    </select>
```

It starts empty and then I fill it with JS taking values from another select :

```
function addToList(sel, value){
   var adding = document.getElementById("cart");
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
   adding.add(option);
   adding.selectedIndex = (adding.options.length - 1);
}
```

This works perfectly fine, my problem is in the servlet whenever I try to get all the values from my "cart" list, as it only returns the one that was selected before the submission:

```
 String [] options = request.getParameterValues("cart");
```

Is there any way to either iterate the select and send all of the values to the servlet? or to get all the parameter values even if they are unselected? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Complete code for the form

```
<form method="POST" action="servlet">
<div id="products-container">
    //I use this list to pick the things I want
    <select id="product-list" size="26" onclick="addToList(this)">
    <%
      List<Product> product = ProductDao.loadProducts();
      for(int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++){
    %>
    <%
      out.write(
       "<option value=\"" + product.get(i).getProductId() + "\">"
       + product.get(i).getProductName() + "</option>");
    %>
    <%
      }
    %>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="cart-container">
    //I use this list to save all the things I already picked, 
    //if I double click an item on the list, it removes said item
    <select id="cart" size="10" name="cart" onDblClick="removeFromList()">
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form>
```

removeFromList code:

```
function removeFromList(sel){
   sel.remove(sel.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: add a hidden field and send all the values comma seperated and split on servlet to get the values

Comment: Would that allow me to remove a value in case I needed it? the list of things I need must allow for both adding and deletion of elements.

Comment: yes you have to write javascript in a way to remove it. like using replace to do that. Add more code like complete form so that I can get clear idea what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Just added the whole form.

Comment: ok give me some time. Let me check

Comment: add your removeFromList code so that I can update it to work

Comment: Added code for the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a function on submit called `selectAll` and made `select` as `multiple` with `ID cart`. if you use jquery code can be reduced further.

```
<form method="POST" action="servlet" onsubmit="selectAll">
<div id="products-container">
    //I use this list to pick the things I want
    <select id="product-list" size="26" onclick="addToList(this)">
    <%
      List<Product> product = ProductDao.loadProducts();
      for(int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++){
    %>
    <%
      out.write(
       "<option value=\"" + product.get(i).getProductId() + "\">"
       + product.get(i).getProductName() + "</option>");
    %>
    <%
      }
    %>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="cart-container">
    //I use this list to save all the things I already picked, 
    //if I double click an item on the list, it removes said item
    <select id="cart" size="10" name="cart" onDblClick="removeFromList()" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
function selectAll(){
    var cartOptions = document.getElementById("cart").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(var i=0;i<cart.length;i++){
        cartOptions[i].setAttribute("selected","true");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!
And I will definetly learn JQuery as soon as possible.